# Expected number of collisions while distributing balls in boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

Suppose we have n balls $b_1, b_2,\cdots , b_n$ and n boxes. Each ball is placed into a box chosen independently and uniformly randomly. A colliding pair is defined as $(b_i,b_j)$, where $i<j$ and $b_i$ and $b_j$ are placed in the same box. We are asked to evaluate the expected number of colliding pairs.

What I did -

Clearly, for any $k$-set of balls in some box, there are $\binom{k}{2}$ colliding pairs in that box.

Next if $C$ is the total number of colliding pairs after randomly placing all the balls in boxes,

$E[C] = E[C_1+C_2+\cdots+C_n]=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}E[C_i]=nE[C_k]$

where $C_k$ is the number of colliding pairs in box $k$ and $E[C_k] = E[C_1]=E[C_2]=\cdots$ .

Now as each box will have $\binom{i}{2} = i(i-1)/2$ colliding pairs if the box contains $i$ balls, we can calculate the expected value as follows -

$\begin{align}
nE[C_k] &= n\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=2}^{n}\binom{i}{2}\text{Pr}\left[i(i-1)\text{ colliding pairs in box k}\right]\right) \\&= n\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=2}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\dfrac{i(i-1)}{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^i\left(\dfrac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n-i}\right)\end{align}$

This can be calculated using various tricks like differentiating the $(1+x)^n$ binomial expansion and so on.

But, the answer $E[C] = \dfrac{n-1}{2}$. Given that the answer is so simple, is there a much simpler/slicker/quicker way to see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT

Yes.  Whenever you are asked to find an expected value, *always* check to see if you can use the linearity of expectations.  Remember that linearity of expectations apply even when variables are dependent!

For any pair $i < j$, let $X_{ij}$ be the indicator variable for whether $(i,j)$ is a colliding pair.

- What is $E[X_{ij}]$?
- How many pairs are there?
- Use linearity of expectation...

Lemme know if you need further help.

Comment: Brilliant ! ^3^

Comment: Omg i'm v dumb. Thanks for the nice answer!!

Comment: @hello_123 - missing shortcuts / tricks in math, esp. in probability, is commonplace and happens to all of us.  don't worry about it!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Continuing the OP's solution, let $B_{1}$ denote the number of balls in box
$1$, so $C_{1}=\dbinom{B_{1}}{2}=\dfrac{B_{1}\left(  B_{1}-1\right)  }{2}$.

Next, one can write $B_{1}=I_{1}+I_{2}+\ldots+I_{n}$, where $I_{k}=\left\{
\begin{array}
[c]{l}%
1\text{, if the ball }k\text{ is in box }1\\
0\text{, otherwise}%
\end{array}
\right.  \quad (k=1,2,\ldots,n)$.

Then $E\left[  B_{1}\right]  =\sum_{k=1}^{n}E\left[  I_{k}\right]  =\sum
_{k=1}^{n}\underbrace{P\left(  \text{the ball }k\text{ is in box }1\right)
}_{p_{k}}=n\cdot\dfrac{1}{n}=1$. The mutual independence of $\left\{
I_{k}\right\}  $ assures that $V\left[  B_{1}\right]  =\sum_{k=1}^{n}V\left[
I_{k}\right]  =\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(  p_{k}-p_{k}^{2}\right)  =n\left(
\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\right)  =\dfrac{n-1}{n}$.

Concluding,
\begin{align*}
E\left[  C\right]    & =nE\left[  C_{1}\right]  =\dfrac{n}{2}\left(  E\left[
\left(  B_{1}-1\right)  ^{2}+B_{1}-1\right]  \right)  \\
& =\dfrac{n}{2}\left(  E\left[  \left(  B_{1}-E\left[  B_{1}\right]  \right)
^{2}\right]  +E\left[  B_{1}\right]  -1\right)  \\
& =\dfrac{n}{2}\left(V\left[  B_{1}\right]  +1-1\right)=\dfrac{n-1}{2}.
\end{align*}
.